# Is there a way to debug live smart contracts on main network?

Tags: contract-debugging, network, geth-debugging

Debug button doesn't work on Remix when targeting a live smart contract. What are my other options?

Can I copy the current main Ethereum network snapshot with ganache and then run my own transactions?

I want to copy the current state, so redeploying the contract to a test network is not an option.

Comment: Can't you recreate the current state on the testnet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Truffle team recently released Portable Solidity Debugger that can be used to debug transactions on the main Ethereum network as they claim http://truffleframework.com/blog/announcing-full-portable-solidity-debugger

> we built it to work with any Ethereum client, so you could debug transactions against the main Ethereum network if you so desired

```
truffle debug <tx hash>
```

It supports:

- Code stepping (over, into, out, next, instruction, etc.)
- Current code location, including the address of the running contract
- Breakpoints
- Watch expressions
- Variable inspection (stack, memory and storage)
- Custom expression evaluation using Solidity variables

I suspect it relies on [transaction tracing](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Tracing:-Introduction) so you will need a full archival node.

Comment: Awesome news, makes me happy to see Ethererum ecosystem going forward every day :)

Comment: Couple of gotchas with this for anyone trying to debug:
1. This only works with a geth full node (not fast synced) with the `debug` rpcapi option enabled. It will NOT work with parity since parity does not understand `debug_traceTransaction`. 2. Although this is not related to the question, by consequence it will not work with the kovan testnet.